# Query for the below requirement

Tags: sql

I have a table with Column Client Code.

There are codes in range of 99990000 and 99999999.

I want all those numbers between this range ( 99990000 -99999999 )

Which are not assigned  to Client Codes.

Please help me with this query.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? What are the table schemas? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you effectively looking for all of the possible client account numbers in the specified range that have not been used?

Comment: You'll need to create a derived table for all possible values between that range, and select from that where the number is not present in the client code column.

Comment: What do you mean by *not assigned to Client Codes*?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select *only* range between `99990000 AND 99999999`

```
SELECT * FROM 
myTable 
WHERE ClientCode BETWEEN (99990000 AND 99999999)
```

If you want to select *excluded* range between `99990000 AND 99999999`

```
SELECT * FROM 
myTable 
WHERE ClientCode NOT BETWEEN (99990000 AND 99999999)
```

Comment: The OP needs the opposite of that `all the numbers between (99990000 -99999999) Which were not assigned to Client Codes`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the question, this would be the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ClientCode BETWEEN 99990000 AND -99999999
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the complete list of possible accounts and then exclude the ones that are in use.

```
/*DECLARE VARIABLES FOR START AND END RANGE*/
DECLARE @StartAccount   AS  INT
DECLARE @EndAccount     AS  INT
SET     @StartAccount   =   99990000
SET     @EndAccount     =   99999999
;
--Generate a list of numbers to check against:..Thanks to Anthony Horne for this
   WITH Nbrs_4( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 0 ),
Nbrs_3( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_4 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_4 n2 ),
Nbrs_2( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_3 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_3 n2 ),
Nbrs_1( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_2 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_2 n2 ),
Nbrs_0( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_1 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_1 n2 ),
Nbrs  ( n ) AS ( SELECT 1 FROM Nbrs_0 n1 CROSS JOIN Nbrs_0 n2 )

SELECT n
FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n)
FROM Nbrs ) D ( n )
WHERE n >= @StartAccount 
 AND n <= @EndAccount 
 AND n NOT IN 
(SELECT ClientCode FROM CustomerTable)  --Exclude Accounts that are in use
```